# SQL query joining tables and comparing sums to return max

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm new to mysql and have a question about joins and adding stuff.

I have the following tables: `books` and `genres`

The books table looks as such:

```
id | name | pages | genre_id
```

The genres table:

```
id | name | category_id
```

I want to get the genre that has the most pages.
So if genre1 has 5 books and each book has 100 pages, there are 500 pages in `genre1` and if `genre2` has 2 books but each book has 300 pages, then `genre2` has 600 pages. The query should return `genre2`.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the genres and total number of pages in them, in descending order, `LIMIT 1` will select the top one.

```
SELECT
    g.name,
    SUM(b.pages) AS p_total
FROM
    books b
    JOIN genres g ON g.id = b.genre_id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY p_total DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3a296d/1/0) that illustrates the below query

```
SELECT g.name, SUM(b.pages)
FROM books AS b
  INNER JOIN genres AS g
  ON b.genre_id = g.id
GROUP BY g.id
ORDER BY SUM(b.pages) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

My MySQL is really rusty, but that sounds simple enough:

```
SELECT G.name
FROM Books AS B INNER JOIN Genres AS G ON B.genre_id = G.id
GROUP BY G.name
ORDER BY SUM(B.pages) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Note that you haven't defined what you want if there's a tie.